# How can I access to node in Firebase who has random key?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to reach projectImageUrl but the problem is in between Projects and project Image URL there is a random key for each project so that each project should have a unique name, So how can I reach to projectImageUrl?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you also show us the content of your `projectImageUrl` node?

Comment: yes you can see it now

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access to a node in Firebase who has a random key?

That's not actually random. As I see in your database schema, you are using as the key for the User object, the value of the UID which is concatenated with the date and time. Both date and time, are already apart of the User object. Adding them along with the UID is really not necessary because the UIDs are already unique. There is no need to add anything else to make it "more" unique. My recommendation is to only use the UID and nothing more. In that case, to get the URLs that exist under the projectImageUrl node, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference projectImageUrlRef = rootRef.child("Projects").child(uid).child("projectImageUrl");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String url = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
projectImageUrlRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be the URLs that exist under projectImageUrl node. If you need to keep the date and time, please change the projectImageUrlRef to:

```
DatabaseReference projectImageUrlRef = rootRef.child("Projects").child(uid + date + time).child("projectImageUrl");
```

Where that date should hold the value of "06-Oct-2020" and the time "16:37:9".